# Is there some Python function like .to_period that could help me extract a fiscal year's week number based on a date?

Tags: python, pandas

Essentially, I want to apply some lambda function(?) of some sort to apply to a column in my dataframe that contains dates. Originally, I used dt.week to extract the week number but the calendar dates don't match up with the fiscal year I'm using (Apr 2019 - Mar 2020).

I have tried using pandas' function to_period('Q-MAR) but that seems to be a little bit off. I have been researching other ways but nothing seems to work properly.

### Apr 1 2019 -> Week 1

### Apr 3 2019 -> Week 1

### Apr 30 2019 -> Week 5

### May 1 2019 -> Week 5

### May 15 2019 -> Week 6

Thank you for any advice or tips in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `DataFrame` which contains the dates with a frequency of weeks:

```
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='01/04/2019',end='31/03/2020', freq='W')
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
```

You can then query `df` for which index the date is smaller than or equal to the value:

```
df.index[df.date <= query_date][-1]
```

This will output the largest index which is smaller than or equal to the date you want to examine. I imagine you can pour this into a lambda yourself?

**NOTE**

This solution has limitations, the biggest one being you have to manually define the datetime dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I did create a fiscal calendar that can be later improvised to create function in spark

```
from fiscalyear import *
beginDate = '2016-01-01'
endDate = '2021-12-31'
#create empty dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame([()])
#create date from given date range 
df1 = df.withColumn("date",explode(expr(f"sequence(to_date('{beginDate}'), to_date('{endDate}'), interval 1 day)")))
# get week 
df1 = df1.withColumn('week',weekofyear(col("date"))).withColumn('year',year(col("date")))

#translate to use pandas in python
df1 = df1.toPandas()
#get fiscal year 
df1['financial_year'] = df1['date'].map(lambda x: x.year if x.month > 3 else x.year-1)
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
#get calendar qtr
df1['quarter_old'] = df1['date'].dt.quarter
#get fiscal calendar
df1['quarter'] = np.where(df1['financial_year']< (df1['year']),df1['quarter_old']+3,df1['quarter_old'])
df1['quarter'] = np.where(df1['financial_year'] == (df1['year']),df1['quarter_old']-1,df1['quarter'])
#get fiscal week by shiftin gas per number of months different from usual calendar
df1["fiscal_week"] = df1.week.shift(91)
df1 = df1.loc[(df1['date'] >= '2020-01-01')]
df1.display()
```